# Do not exit if the file is not found python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I have a list of filenames
When reading a file, it comes out with an error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 229, in <module>
    f = open(i, 'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'directory_home.json'
```

How can I skip the error and complete the rest of the files?

code

```py
file = ["directory_home.json", "directory_ever.json", "home.json", "home.json"]
for i in file: 
    f = open(i, 'r')
    data = json.load(f) 
    for i in data['name']:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Look up Try and Except statements

Comment: Check if [it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists-without-exceptions) first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this. Note that 'pass' goes to next iteration. 'Continue' would repeat iteration (in this case useless). 'Break' would end iteration.

```
file = ["directory_home.json", "directory_ever.json", "home.json", "home.json"]
for i in file:
    try:
        f = open(i, 'r')
        data = json.load(f) 
        for i in data['name']:
            print(i)
        f.colse()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File does not exist")
        pass
```

Comment: PEP 8: E722 do not use bare 'except'

Comment: And close the file, please

Comment: `continue` does not repeat iteration, it skips all the code remaining in the loop and jumps to the next iteration. In this particular case, a `continue` instead of the `pass` would work exactly the same because it is the last statement in the loop so there's nothing to skip.

Answer (score 3):

Two options.

**Option 1: `os.path.isfile`**

```
import os
file = ["directory_home.json", "directory_ever.json", "home.json", "home.json"]
for i in file:
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        f = open(i)
        data = json.load(f) 
        for i in data['name']:
            print(i)
    else:
        continue # or whatever you want to do.
```

**Option 2**: Exception handling

```
file = ["directory_home.json", "directory_ever.json", "home.json", "home.json"]
for i in file: 
    try:
        f = open(i, 'r')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        continue # or whatever
    data = json.load(f) 
    for i in data['name']:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pur your code in a try-except statement, like this

```
try:
     file = ["directory_home.json", "directory_ever.json", "home.json", "home.json"]
     for i in file: 
     f = open(i, 'r')
     data = json.load(f) 
     for i in data['name']:
           print(i)
except FileNotFoundError as e:
     # log exception and do whatever you want
     pass
```

In this way, if your code raises an exception because the file si not present, you are able ti handle It.
Please remember that in the code above, just the exception due to a not existing file si catch. This means that if another exception occurs the code will raise a traceback